# AWS - ECS task failed with "reason": "RESOURCE:PORTS"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

While running some task using AWS ECS I'm getting the below error:

Failed : `"reason": "RESOURCE:PORTS"`

With my further analysis I found the scheduler cannot assign the task to an instance because it requires a fixed port that is already taken. I've only one port and I can't assign any other port to it.

Is there any way I can release the port so that I can reuse it for another task through ECS?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this unhelpful error message when running Scheduled Tasks with EventBridge.  When registering the Rule in EventBridge, you need to open up the “Compute Options” toggle and select a capacity provider strategy.  In my case I just selected the option for using the cluster default.  Previously I had selected "EC2" as the "Launch Strategy" instead, which was causing the task to fail with `"reason": "RESOURCE:PORTS"`.  When I switched to capacity provider strategy, the tasks ran successfully.

The AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/api_failures_messages.html) were not super helpful in my case.

I hope this saves someone the hours it took me to learn it!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to kill the task which is using that port, then you can use the port for some other task. You can also use dynamic port mapping to avoid port conflict by mentioning the host port 0. You can use dynamic port mapping [1] with loadbalancer as described in this document or without load balancer by just mentioning hostport 0. In the later case you will have to check the port to which it is mapped and then expose it to outside for your application.

[1] https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamic-port-mapping-ecs/